# KQL with multi value term field values - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, kql

I have a multivalue page property(MyProperty) pointing to a term set and I have a managed property(MyManagedProperty)

Stored values are 
 MyManagedProperty:Value1; Value2; Value3 - at least 10 items has these values
 Page.MyProperty:Value1; Value2   - current page has these values

When I search like this

{?{|{Page.MyProperty}:MyManagedProperty}}

I expect to see some results but nothing comes back. I had this query in another site and it works but this newly created site has a problem.

Any idea on how to trouble shoot this issue?
Is there some sort of SharePoint Online Search Timer Job needs to kick in before this thing works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
{?{|{MyManagedProperty}:Page.MyProperty}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having Search as one of my primary fields of focus I have had similar issues a lot. It seems like the most productive approach is to verify that the search results contains the field in question and the values are as expected.
My suggestion is the inspect the raw search result using SP Query Tool from github, then you will know if the mapping is wrong

Comment: I looked at the values. Managed properties populated properly but not working for some reason...